# Drawing a line at an angle from a set point not pointing in the correct direction

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to draw a line in a direction, a length, and a start point. I need to do this because my graphics library has lines with a start and end point. `line(x1, y1, x2, y2)`

However, the formula I'm using to convert this doesn't seem to work.

```py
def radialpoint(xc, yc, length, angle):
    angle = radians(angle)

    return (int(xc + length * cos(angle)), int(yc + length * sin(angle)))
```

I used this code. It's basically the example used by everybody else who had this problem. But, when I use it, it seems to point in the wrong direction: i.e 5 degrees points downwards. I thought the angle needed flipping round, so I tried adding `angle = (angle - 180) % 360` at the start to flip it around, but it does the exact same thing. Changing the angle number doesn't even seem to do much, it's the length number that changes the line. But it still doesn't do it right, a 'length' of 180 isn't 180 degrees. Does anybody know what could be causing this, and what code I should have used?

Comment: What direction does your initial `angle` with value 0 point?  How about 90 degrees, what direction?

Comment: Where did you add `angle=(angle-180)%360`? If you did that after converting it to radians, then you are trying to concoct new radians from a degrees formula.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy The problem was that I had placed the wrong numbers in a completely different part of the code. It’s not really related to the question, and so not useful as an answer